# How to split list of inputs in a tensorflow keras Model call method?

Tags: python, tensorflow

How are we supposed to split the inputs? Getting various errors. `tf.split` seems like it should work but not sure that is correct?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras

tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')

m = 250  # samples
n_x = 1  # dim of x
n_tau = 11

x = (2 * np.random.rand(m, n_x).astype(np.float64) - 1) * 2 
i = np.argsort(x[:, 0]) 
x = x[i]  # to make plotting nicer
A = np.random.randn(n_x, 1)
y = x ** 2 + 0.3 * x + 0.4 * np.random.randn(m, 1).astype(np.float64)
y = y.dot(A)  # y is 1d
# y = y.squeeze()
tau = np.linspace(1.0 / n_tau, 1 - 1.0 / n_tau, n_tau).astype(np.float64)
tau = tau[:, None]

def loss(tau_y, u):
    tau, y = tau_y
    tf.debugging.assert_rank(y, 2, f"y should be rank 2")
    u = y[:, None, :] - u[None, :, :]
    tf.debugging.assert_rank(tau, 2, f"tau should be rank 2")
    tau = tau[None, :, :]
    res = u ** 2 * (tau - tf.where(u <= np.float64(0.0), np.float64(1.0), np.float64(0.0)))
    return tf.reduce_sum(tf.reduce_mean(res, axis=[1, 2]), axis=0)


tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')
class My(tf.keras.models.Model):
   def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()
       self._my_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, dtype=tf.float64)
   def call(self, inputs):
       tau, y = inputs
       tf.print(tau.shape, y.shape)
       return self._my_layer(tau)


model = My()
u = model((tau, y))
loss((tau, y), model((tau, y)))
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=loss)
model.fit((tau, y), (tau, y)) # fails
```

This works for a call but not from within a *compiled* model. Some weird list comprehension error.

```
~/j.py in loss(tau_y, u)
     21 
     22 def loss(tau_y, u):
---> 23     tau, y = tau_y
     24     tf.debugging.assert_rank(y, 2, f"y should be rank 2")
     25     u = y[:, None, :] - u[None, :, :]

~/anaconda3/envs/37nightly/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in __iter__(self)
    537   def __iter__(self):
    538     if not context.executing_eagerly():
--> 539       self._disallow_iteration()
    540 
    541     shape = self._shape_tuple()

~/anaconda3/envs/37nightly/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in _disallow_iteration(self)
    533     else:
    534       # Default: V1-style Graph execution.
--> 535       self._disallow_in_graph_mode("iterating over `tf.Tensor`")
    536 
    537   def __iter__(self):

~/anaconda3/envs/37nightly/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in _disallow_in_graph_mode(self, task)
    513     raise errors.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError(
    514         "{} is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate"
--> 515         " this function with @tf.function.".format(task))
    516 
    517   def _disallow_bool_casting(self):

OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.
```

UPDATE:

Do this? But then you get another error to do with keras:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras

tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')

m = 250  # samples
n_x = 1  # dim of x
n_tau = 11

x = (2 * np.random.rand(m, n_x).astype(np.float64) - 1) * 2
i = np.argsort(x[:, 0])
x = x[i]  # to make plotting nicer
A = np.random.randn(n_x, 1)
y = x ** 2 + 0.3 * x + 0.4 * np.random.randn(m, 1).astype(np.float64)
y = y.dot(A)  # y is 1d
y = y[:, :, None]
tau = np.linspace(1.0 / n_tau, 1 - 1.0 / n_tau, n_tau).astype(np.float64)
tau = tau[None, :, None]

def loss(tau_y, u):
    tau = tau_y[0]
    y = tau_y[1]
    u = y - u
    res = u ** 2 * (tau - tf.where(u <= np.float64(0.0), np.float64(1.0), np.float64(0.0)))
    return tf.reduce_sum(tf.reduce_mean(res, axis=[1, 2]), axis=0)

tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')
class My(tf.keras.models.Model):
   def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()
       self._my_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, dtype=tf.float64)
   def call(self, inputs):
       tau = inputs[0]
       y = inputs[1]
       tf.print(tau.shape, y.shape)
       return self._my_layer(tau)


model = My()
u = model((tau, y)) # calling model works
l = loss((tau, y), model((tau, y))) # call loss works
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=loss)

# this fails with the error below
model.fit((tau, y), (tau, y))
# ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), for inputs ['output_1'] but instead got the following list of 2 arrays: [array([[[0.09090909],
#         [0.17272727],
#         [0.25454545],
#         [0.33636364],
#         [0.41818182],
#         [0.5       ],
#         [0.58181818],
#         [0.66363636],
#         [0.74545455],
#  ...
```

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32546

Comment: "Some weird error" that is not very helpful towards solving the issue. Please add to the question the complete example including the compiling part and the exact error you are receving with its stack trace.

Comment: Also your example has two syntax errors (`class My` instead of `def My`, and a missing parenthesis in the last line), and after fixing them it doesn't run either because NumPy random arrays need to be converted to `np.float32`. Calling `model.compile()` doesn't seem to give an error. Please post a self-contained reproducible example in the question.

Comment: @jdehesa repro above.

Comment: @mathtick, What is the Tensorflow Version that you are using. I am Encountering different errors when tried to reproduce your code in Google Colab. With `Tensorflow Version 1.x`, the error is `ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 0 and 3 for 'Select' (op: 'Select') with input shapes: [250,11,1], [], [].`. 

With `Tensorflow Version 2.x`, the error is `ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 11, 250
  y sizes: 11, 250
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.`. Can you please share the complete repro code.

Comment: @TensorflowWarriors I only use tensorflow 2, 2.1.0 as of now.

Comment: Have updated with a directly slicing method that hits the other keras error to do with compile. Can't remember if I posted a quetstion about that one yet or not.